# Sum the total employment time/year for employees / plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

a 'job' table as follow

[image: job table]

How do I find the total years of employment for all the employees?

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| emplid |  record   |     action      |      effect dt   |
+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
|      1 |         0 |   terminate     | 8/9/2010         |
|      1 |         0 |   hire          |         5/6/2006 |
|      1 |         0 |   terminate     | 3/4/2005         |
|      1 |         0 |   hire          |         1/1/2003 |
|      1 |         1 |   hire          |         1/1/2006 |
|      1 |         1 |   terminate     | 5/5/2004         |
|      1 |         1 |   promote       | 4/4/2003         |
|      1 |         1 |   hire          |         3/3/2002 |
|      1 |         1 |   terminate     | 2/2/2001         |
|      1 |         1 |   hire          |         1/1/2000 |
|      2 |         0 |   rehire        | 6/7/2013         |
|      2 |         0 |   terminate     | 5/6/2011         |
|      2 |         0 |   rehire        | 3/3/2010         |
|      2 |         0 |   terminate     | 2/2/2009         |
|      2 |         0 |   hire          |         1/1/2008 |
+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Would you care to explain the data? It seems to be  a bit messy. What is relationship between EMPID and RECORD? How can same permutation of EMPID and RECORD have multiple occurrences of same value of ACTION???

Comment: Hi APC - Thanks for quick feedback! Yes it is messy indeed... in this table employee could've have multiple job (dual employment or more) in different places, when employee hired from other place, a new record generated... I am hoping a query that could sum the employment time. (exclude the time from terminate to the next hire/rehire date)    Let me know if I have answered the question.

Comment: Also, which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 12 or later, use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to find pairs of `(re)hire`/`terminate` entries and then use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` to find the duration then group and sum to get the total:

```sql
SELECT emplid,
       record,
       SUM(
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(
           COALESCE( terminate_dt, SYSDATE ),
           hire_dt
         ) / 12
       ) AS hire_years
FROM   job
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY emplid, record
  ORDER     BY effect_dt
  MEASURES
    FIRST( hire.effect_dt )     AS hire_dt,
    LAST( terminate.effect_dt ) AS terminate_dt
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( hire changes* terminate? )
  DEFINE
    hire      AS hire.action IN ( 'hire', 'rehire' ),
    changes   AS changes.action NOT IN ( 'hire', 'rehire', 'terminate' ),
    terminate AS terminate.action IN ( 'terminate' )
)
GROUP BY
       emplid,
       record
```

*(Assuming that if an employee has been hired but there is no later termination entry then they are still employed.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE job ( emplid, record, action, effect_dt ) AS
SELECT 1, 0, 'terminate', DATE '2010-09-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, 'hire',      DATE '2006-06-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, 'terminate', DATE '2005-04-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0, 'hire',      DATE '2003-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'hire',      DATE '2006-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'terminate', DATE '2004-05-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'promote',   DATE '2003-04-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'hire',      DATE '2002-03-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'terminate', DATE '2001-02-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'hire',      DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, 'rehire',    DATE '2013-07-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, 'terminate', DATE '2011-06-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, 'rehire',    DATE '2010-03-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, 'terminate', DATE '2009-02-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, 'hire',      DATE '2008-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> EMPLID | RECORD |                                HIRE_YEARS
> -----: | -----: | ----------------------------------------:
>      1 |      0 |  6.51344086021505376344086021505376344086
>      1 |      1 | 18.18784323974512146555157307845479888494
>      2 |      0 |  9.75773571286340103544404619673436877738
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a70478d3f759268e5d1a8fa20f0e95a)*

Comment: MATCH_RECOGNIZE is the obvious solution to this sort of problem, which is why I asked the Seeker which version they are using.